# How to access static method in another class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a class called: Sample, where I declared a static method named calculate() which takes a number and return it is square root. This program is saved in 'static_method_2.py'

```
import math
class Sample:
    data = 10
    @staticmethod
    def calculate(x):
        return(math.sqrt(x))
```

I want to access this calculate method in another python program.(both python program in same folder)

```
import static_method_2
num = int(input('Enter Number for square root \n'))
# print(method.data)
print("Square root of {} is {}".format(num, static_method_2.calculate(num)))
```

When I am running 2nd program, it's showing error:

> AttributeError: module 'static_method_2' has no attribute 'calculate'

Can anyone please suggest how to get rid of this problem, or where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the class name after the module name will do:

```
print("Square root of {} is {}".format(num, static_method_2.Sample.calculate(num)))
```

Comment: Why I can't do like this:
when I am writing import static_method_2.Sample as sam and trying to use sam.calculate(num), it's not working.

Comment: `from static_method_2 import Sample as sam` and then try to use `sam.calculate(num)` or `import static_method_2.Sample.calculate as sam` and then try to use `sam.calculate(num)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to import Sample from the other file and then call Sample. calculate

Comment: when I am writing import static_method_2.Sample as sam and trying to use sam.calculate(num), it's not working.